# How to check if three values are equal, and printing an output based on that

Tags: python

So, im making a command terminal that sends emails, tells you the time, and even generates passwords. Anyway the point being, lots of code in one spot means at least one part is bound to fail, and that part on my code currently is the slots command. The slots command is a fake gambling game. The problem is when checking if someone actually won. When someone wins the slots game, it will print "you win!" and otherwise will tell you that you lose, but instead, it always says that the user lost. Heres the code that actually is needed (dont want to make you look through a blob of 345 lines of code)

```
import random

def slots_p5():
    print("  " + slots_p2)
    print("» " + slots_p3)
    print("  " + slots_p4)


def find( slotOne, slotTwo, slotThree):
    if slotOne == slotTwo == slotThree:
        print ("\nYou win")
    else:
        print ("\nUnfortuneatly, you lose!")

slots = ["","","","7️⃣"]
slotOne = (random.choice(slots))
slotTwo = (random.choice(slots))
slotThree = (random.choice(slots))
slots_p2 = (random.choice(slots) + random.choice(slots) + random.choice(slots))
slots_p3 = slotOne + slotTwo + slotThree
slots_p4 = (random.choice(slots) + random.choice(slots) + random.choice(slots))

slots_p5()
find( slotOne, slotTwo, slotThree,)
slots_p2 = (random.choice(slots) + random.choice(slots) + random.choice(slots))
slots_p3 = slotOne + slotTwo + slotThree
slots_p4 = (random.choice(slots) + random.choice(slots) + random.choice(slots))
slotOne = (random.choice(slots))
slotTwo = (random.choice(slots))
slotThree = (random.choice(slots))
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code runs fine for me, you have to run the code many times to get a case where there are three in a row, but it does happen if you run it about a 100 times. indeed the syntax

```
if slotOne == slotTwo == slotThree:
```

was a surprise to learn that it works but it does

Comment: Yup! Chained operators are *awesome*. [PEP documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0535/) if anyone's interested

Comment: Agree. Check this [document](https://ke-zhang-rd.github.io/krystal/comparision.html) if you wanna see more examples about chained comparison.

Comment: Tysm, now i know its not a problem with that part of code. Im not sure what i did.

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine. Since it's generating slots randomly and all slots must be the same, you will definitely not get wins a lot. It's all about probability.